# Keep JMS consumer alive for messages

Tags: java, jms

I'm writing a simple java program that create a JMSConsumer. I want that the consumer wait until the producer published something, also after that the main program is terminated. This is my main:

```
    JMSContext context;
    Destination destination; 
    JMSConsumer consumer;
    
    JmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = createJMSConnectionFactory();

    setJMSProperties(connectionFactory);

    System.out.println("MQ Test: Connecting to " + HOST + ", Port " + PORT + ", Channel " + CHANNEL
    + ", Connecting to " + QUEUE_NAME);

    try {
        context = connectionFactory.createContext(); 
        destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME); 
        consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); 

        MessageListener ml = new DemoMessageListener(); 
        consumer.setMessageListener(ml); 
        
        System.out.println("The message listener is running."); // (Because the connection is started by default)

        context.start();
        
        
    } catch (Exception e){}
```

The problem is that when the program arrives at the bottom of the main, the program ends.
The result that I'm trying to obtain is something like basicConsuime of RabbitMq (example below):

```
public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout");
String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, "");

System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
};
channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
}
```

When the main ends, the thread that read the message is still alive, and the deliverCallback is called everytime a message is sent to the queue.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve here? If your program only has one thread, you don't need to use a `MessageListener` at all -- just call `receive()` in a loop to get each message. Or just put a long `Thread.sleep()` at the end of your `main()`. It's hard to know what to suggest, as I don't know how you want the program to behave.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only want to do the same as your 'basic consume' you can something like this (forget about your Demo listener, etc.):

```
  ...
  try {
    context = connectionFactory.createContext(); 
    destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME); 
    consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); 

    /*
    MessageListener ml = new DemoMessageListener(); 
    consumer.setMessageListener(ml); 
    
    System.out.println("The message listener is running."); // (Because the connection is started by default)

    context.start();
    */
    
    String  body = consumer.receiveBody(String.class);
    System.out.println("Received message body: " + body);
    
} catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: This code works only if there is already a message in the queue.I think that you don't understand my problem: the problem isn't read a message from the queue, the problem is find a way to keep the receiver alive ( also when the main program ends ) to listen to the queue. The 'basic consume' example implements exactly this scenario: also when the main ends, if a new message is added to the queue, the deliverCallback is called.

Comment: Ah ok, so then would an endless loop work for you ? take your original code and add: while(true) { Thread.sleep(1000); }

Answer (score 0):

In current situation as soon as main ends process will be terminated and all threads associated with process as well.

There are couple of options to achieve what you mentioned.

1. you deploy your code in any of container like tomcat as application
   which will keep process running.
2. Other way is keep your main thread in busy waiting and using thread.notify to terminate if required.

Comment: Sure, you could do either of those things -- but does the application need that complexity? If all it has to do is get messages and process them synchronous, it can just call `recieve()` repeatedly. More complicated needs merit more complicated solutions ;)